# Attaching parameters to the URL of a Rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is a silly question but weird enough I Googled it, I am sure i had seen it before in Rails guides but now couldn't find it.

I want to attach parameters to my URL.

My initial url is this: `"http://localhost:3000/pharmacy/patients"`

Now I attach one URL with string concatination in JavaScript and it will be this:

```
"http://localhost:3000/pharmacy/patients?provider=234"
```

And still good.

Now I want to attach a **second parameter** named `thera_class` and its **values** are *strings with spaces between them like "Nasal Congestion"*

If I want to also concatenate that second parameter to it, How would the URL look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it would look is:

```
http://localhost:3000/pharmacy/patients?provider=234&thera_class=Nasal Congestion
```

To be extra strict, spaces are replaced by %20 in the URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/pharmacy/patients?provider=234&thera_class=Nasal%20Congestion
```

Comment: Thanks, since I am generating the URL with string concatenation in JavaScript, should I also hard code it for spaces or doesn't need to do that?

Comment: The safe way is with %20